# Delay in drag/drop of UIElement in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, uielement

I'm using the `ManipulationDelta` event handler to drag and drop a simple ellipse in a canvas across the screen. I'm using the standard approach posted online in several places. Following is the code in my event handler:

```
Ellipse dragableItem = sender as Ellipse;
TranslateTransform translateTransform = dragableItem.RenderTransform as TranslateTransform;
double newPosX = Canvas.GetLeft(dragableItem) + translateTransform.X + e.Delta.Translation.X;
double newPosY = Canvas.GetTop(dragableItem) + translateTransform.Y + e.Delta.Translation.Y;

if (!isCanvasBoundary(newPosX, TestCanvas.ActualWidth - dragableItem.ActualWidth, 0))
      translateTransform.X += e.Delta.Translation.X;

if (!isCanvasBoundary(newPosY, TestCanvas.ActualHeight - dragableItem.ActualHeight, 0))
      translateTransform.Y += e.Delta.Translation.Y;
```

The drag and drop operation works fine, but there's a nasty delay of around 1 second between when the user begins dragging to when the ellipse actually changes its position. I can see by printing to the Debugger that the event handler itself finishes executing almost instantly, so I'm guessing it has something to do a pre-programmed refresh rate for all UIElements on the screen that's causing this delay?

Is there anyway around this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem some time ago. I guess that the delay is to decide whether the gesture is drag or tap. It's hard to touch a screen without any accidental drag.

To eliminate this lag, you can use `PointerMove` and `PointerPressed` events. Here's my example. You have canvas with two ellipses which can be dragged without any delay.

**XAML**

```
<Grid>
    <Canvas x:Name="Board" PointerMoved="Canvas_PointerMoved" Background="Black">
        <Ellipse Width="64" Height="64" Fill="Red"
                 Canvas.Left="32" Canvas.Top="128" PointerPressed="Ellipse_PointerPressed"/>
        <Ellipse Width="96" Height=" 96" Fill="Blue"
                 Canvas.Left="128" Canvas.Top="16" PointerPressed="Ellipse_PointerPressed"/>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

As you can see, I'm handling `PointerMoved` event in canvas and `PointerPressed` event in ellipses. It's important that the background of the canvas is not transparent to handle touch events.

**C#**

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    UIElement draggedItem = null;
    Point offset;

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
    }

    private void Ellipse_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        draggedItem = sender as UIElement;
        offset = e.GetCurrentPoint(draggedItem).Position;
    }

    private void Canvas_PointerMoved(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (draggedItem == null)
            return;

        Point dragPoint = e.GetCurrentPoint(Board).Position;
        Canvas.SetLeft(draggedItem, dragPoint.X - offset.X);
        Canvas.SetTop(draggedItem, dragPoint.Y - offset.Y);
    }
}
```

I think the code is quite simple and understandable. I use `PointerPressed` to decide which object is dragged. I'm also calculating some offset, because we want to move the object relative to the point where user touches. 

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated! One slight issue with this was that the last moved ellipse would change position even when the user taps on a portion of the canvas where the ellipse isn't located. To remedy this I added a `PointerReleased` event and a simple bool variable which is set it to true in the `PointerPressed` and back to false in `PointerReleased`. Then in `PointerMoved` I'd check the bool and only move the ellipse if it was true.
Also, I found that printing anything in the Debugger from the `PointerMoved` event introduces a substantial lag.

Comment: @Ali250 An easier way I found was to set  `draggedItem = null;` in the PointerReleased event rather than setting up a new bool variable

Comment: great alternative solution +1.