# Overriding Manipulation Delta of user control

Tags: c#, user-controls, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1, manipulationdelta

I have a user control which moves with my finger movement.The user control has its own manipulation delta set.
My problem is , when My finger is on the user control and I am trying to move it up , I am having lag because it is not moving up with my finger.
The user control appears when I long tap on my screen , the location of the user control is whereever my finger is pressed . It moves with my finger whereever I move my finger , but once my finger goes on the user control I am not having smooth movements .

Any help would be appreciated.
**The XAML is**

```
<Page x:Name="page1" 
    x:Class="controlMagnifier.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:controlMagnifier"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid x:Name="ParentGrid" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" PointerReleased="ParentGrid_OnPointerReleased"  >
        <Canvas x:Name="InkPresenter" Height="auto" Width="auto">

            <Image Stretch="None" x:Name="image2"  >
                <Image.Source >
                    <BitmapImage UriSource="/Assets/wallpaper.jpg" />
                </Image.Source>
            </Image>
        </Canvas>

        <local:MagnifierUsercontrol  x:Name="MagnifyTip"  Visibility="Collapsed" ManipulationDelta="MagnifyTip_ManipulationDelta" ManipulationMode="All" >
            <local:MagnifierUsercontrol.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform/>
            </local:MagnifierUsercontrol.RenderTransform>
        </local:MagnifierUsercontrol>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

**The CS Code Is**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Windows.UI.Popups;
using Windows.UI.Input;
using Windows.Storage;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging;



// The Blank Page item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=234238

namespace controlMagnifier
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public const int XAxis = 105;
        public const int YAxis = 270;
        public Thickness margin;



        public WriteableBitmap CurrentBitmapObj, CurrentCroppedImage = null;
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            ParentGrid.Holding += Grid_Holding;
            image2.PointerMoved += InkCanvas_PointerMoved;
            image2.PointerReleased += ParentGrid_OnPointerReleased;
            image2.CacheMode=new BitmapCache();
            StoreCrrentImage();
        }



/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
        private void Grid_Holding(object sender, HoldingRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Point p;
            try
            {
                Point p = e.GetPosition(ParentGrid);

                double height = MagnifyTip.Height;
                double width = MagnifyTip.Width;

                margin = MagnifyTip.Margin;
                margin.Left = p.X - XAxis;
                margin.Right = p.Y - YAxis;
                MagnifyTip.Margin = margin;
               // MagnifyTip.Margin = new Thickness(p.X - XAxis, p.Y - YAxis, 0, 0);
                MagnifyTip.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }


        }


        private  void InkCanvas_PointerMoved(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            try
            {
                PointerPoint pt = e.GetCurrentPoint(image2);
                Point currentContactPt = pt.Position;


                double xValue = currentContactPt.X;
                double yValue = currentContactPt.Y;


                //  MagnifyTip.
                double height = MagnifyTip.Height;
                double width = MagnifyTip.Width;


                MagnifyTip.image1.ImageSource = CropBitmap(currentContactPt);

                MagnifyTip.Margin = new Thickness(xValue - XAxis, yValue - YAxis, 0, 0);

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }

            finally
            {e.Handled = true;}

        }

        private async void StoreCrrentImage()
        {

            try
            {
StorageFile storageFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/wallpaper.jpg", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

                using (
                    Windows.Storage.Streams.IRandomAccessStream fileStream =
                        await storageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
                {
                    BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();

                    await bitmapImage.SetSourceAsync(fileStream);
                    WriteableBitmap writeableBitmap =
                        new WriteableBitmap(bitmapImage.PixelWidth, bitmapImage.PixelHeight);
                    fileStream.Seek(0);
                    await writeableBitmap.SetSourceAsync(fileStream);
                    CurrentBitmapObj = writeableBitmap;
                    writeableBitmap.Invalidate();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception )
            {

                throw;
            }


            finally
            {}

            }

        /// <summary>
        /// This method crops the image by accepting x and y as Arguments
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="point"></param>
        /// <returns>Cropped Image</returns>
        private WriteableBitmap CropBitmap(Point point)
        {
            try
            {
                CurrentCroppedImage = CurrentBitmapObj.Crop(Convert.ToInt32(point.X), Convert.ToInt32(point.Y), 100, 100);
               // var resized = CurrentCroppedImage.Resize(200, 300, WriteableBitmapExtensions.Interpolation.Bilinear);

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }


            return CurrentCroppedImage;


        }

        private void MagnifyTip_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Point p;
            p.X = e.Delta.Translation.X;
            p.Y = e.Delta.Translation.Y;
            var Dragme = (CompositeTransform)MagnifyTip.RenderTransform;
            Dragme.TranslateX += p.X;
            Dragme.TranslateY += p.Y;
            // MagnifyTip.controlCanvas.SetValue(Canvas.SetLeft, p.X);
        }




        private void ParentGrid_OnPointerReleased(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MagnifyTip.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
           // throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

}
```

The user control looks like [image: the user control comes up just at the place of tapping and holding. Any movement will only happen while the finger is still tapped and moved around.]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid the lag which is intentionally implemented in `ManipulationDelta` to distinguish it from `Tap`, use `PointerMove` instead.

I have answered similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28796912/delay-in-drag-drop-of-uielement-in-windows-phone-8-1/28799752#28799752).

Comment: Hi , Thanks for the reply. See , the whole control moves with my pointerpressed event that is on an image in the background. So would it be feasible for you to look into my XAML and C# and help me with that

Comment: I am stil unable to resolve it actually !! Its not working !! any help ?