# Windows Phone 8.1 RT: how to prevent manipulation event throw object?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I'm new C# beginer. I want to prevent throwing XAML's object by manipulation event. My app is developed in Windows Phone 8.1 RT.

I have XAML's REctangle:

```
<Canvas x:Name="MyCanvas" Background="White">
        <Rectangle Name="TestRectangle"
          Width="100" Height="200" Fill="Blue" 
          ManipulationMode="All"/>
</Canvas>
```

In MainPage:

```
public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        // Handle manipulation events.
        TestRectangle.ManipulationDelta += Drag_ManipulationDelta;
        dragTranslation = new TranslateTransform();
        TestRectangle.RenderTransform = this.dragTranslation;

        this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
    }
void Drag_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Move the rectangle.
            dragTranslation.X += e.Delta.Translation.X;
            dragTranslation.Y += e.Delta.Translation.Y;
    }

    private void TestRectangle_PointerPressed(object sender,
PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Rectangle rect = sender as Rectangle;

        // Change the size of the Rectangle
        if (null != rect)
        {
            rect.Width = 250;
            rect.Height = 150;
        }
    }
    private void TestRectangle_PointerReleased(object sender,
PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Rectangle rect = sender as Rectangle;

        // Reset the dimensions on the Rectangle
        if (null != rect)
        {
            rect.Width = 200;
            rect.Height = 100;
        }
    }
    private void TestRectangle_PointerExited(object sender,
PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Rectangle rect = sender as Rectangle;

        // Finger moved out of Rectangle before the pointer exited event
        // Reset the dimensions on the Rectangle
        if (null != rect)
        {
            rect.Width = 200;
            rect.Height = 100;
        }
    }
```

How to move object whitout throwing when user exit event ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that by 'throwing' you mean you want to remove the inertial aspect of your rectangle? In that case remove the `ManipulationMode` setter from your XAML code and insert this line in your page's constructor (C#):

```
TestRectangle.ManipulationMode = ManipulationMode.TranslateX | ManipulationMode.TranslateY;
```

That should remove the intertial effect you're talking about. As a side note though, this method of moving UIElements will give you a pretty annoying lag. I faced a similar problem a little while ago and the issue was resolved by using a different approach:

[Delay in drag/drop of UIElement in Windows Phone 8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28796912/delay-in-drag-drop-of-uielement-in-windows-phone-8-1)

Comment: I got it. Thank you very much, that code is nice :)) !